# Cокращение ссылок (принцип работы)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express

Всем привет. Не могу понять принцип работы сервиса сокращения ссылок.
Представим у меня есть база (id, link, short_link). Находясь на своем сайте все ясно, как через short_link открывать link. А вот как сделать открытие link через short_link в браузере, или как ссылку на другом ресурсе? Другими словами, как при нажатии на short_link заставить открываться саму link.

P.S. Думал про редирект, но опять же, как на каждую short_link повесить сой редирект.

В общем натолкните на мысль или еще лучше, дайте кусок кода для понимания

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$name = 'linksdb';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM links';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item['short_link']) {
        header('Location:' . $item['link']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Именно так, на каждую ссылку свой редирект, данные хранить можно в БД, т.е. вы заводите табличку с двумя полями(или больше) первое поле-короткая ссылка, второе поле- полная ссылка, и делаете редирект

Comment: Вся проблема в том, как его реализовать, этот редирект?)

Comment: Всего одной коммандой `header('Location: http://example.com/New/URL/ ');`

Comment: Как и ожидалось, он выводит последнюю ссылку. Как связать link и short_link?

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе

Comment: _Как связать link и short_link?_ ты же прямо в вопросе пишешь, что _есть база (id, link, short_link)_

Comment: Покажите пример сылки которую вы хотите получить, от этого зависит как именно нужно заполнять переменную $url а код примерно такой `$query = "SELECT * FROM links where shot_link=$url"; `

Comment: В данный момент короткие ссылки в виде http://test/1.php, http://test/2.php и т.д

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$name = 'linksdb';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

$url = $_GET['q'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM links where short_link = '$url' limit 1";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  header("Location:  {$row['link']}" );
```

Короткие ссылки для тестов:

```
example.com/q=HJJASD
example.com/q=dfggdD
```

в БД:

```
short_link    link
HJJASD        {куда хотите редирект со ссылки example.com/q=HJJASD}
dfggdD        {куда хотите редирект со ссылки example.com/q=dfggdD}
```

***код для примера, входящие параметры обязательно нужно фильтровать***

Comment: А как можно обработать ссылки вида example.com/HJJASD ?

Comment: @Canty А вот это уже зависит от используемого веб сервера :) какой сервер у вас ?

Comment: Open Server или вы не про это?)

Comment: Почти, apache \ nginx ?(openserver умеет и в то и в то)

Comment: apache показывает

Comment: mod_rewrite использовать